# How to get Id of the selected listitem of dropdown field

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I have a dropdown field which is a lookup containing values. I need to get the ID of the selected value whenever we change.
 I tried using the following. I didnt get any response

$ (document).ready(function(){

$("#ctl00_m_g_8c84c77a_5db3_4a23_9869_d6079afd3bd5_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup").change(function()
 {
alert("hi");
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
});

alert(id);
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID of the control will differ, try to use `$("[id$='Lookup']")` to get an element ending with "Lookup".

Then you can use `.val()` to get the selected value of the dropdown:
`var id= $("[id$='Lookup']").val();`

Comment: thnks for the info

Comment: So, did it work or not? :P

Comment: Then please please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

That's correct as suggested by Robert. But just in case, if there are more than one look up columns add an extra filter as shown in the below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("[id$='_Lookup'][title='<<FieldName>>']").length > 0) {
            $("[id$='_Lookup'][title='<<FieldName>>']").change(function () {
                alert($("[id$='_Lookup'][title='<<FieldName>>']").val());
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Replace `<<FieldName>>` with your Field Title.